# how to change my code to correct python(pyTelegramBotAPI) threads can only be started once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I create a telegram bot. I start the timer on the button. Below is the following code:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):            
            time.sleep(5)
            print("my thread")     
                        
stopFlag = Event()
thread = MyThread(stopFlag)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def buttons(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Запуск таймера 1':
            if thread.is_alive():
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "wait for the timer to end")                
            else: 
                thread.start()
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "timer started!")
```

When I click the button after the timer expires, I get "threads can only be run once", which makes sense since I don't have a multithreaded version of the code. How to make a multithreaded option so that the timer can be started indefinitely?

Answer (score 0):

From the [threading docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive):

> is_alive()
>
> Return whether the thread is alive.
>
> This method returns True just before the run() method starts until
> just after the run() method terminates.

After it's finished, `thread.is_alive()` returns you `False` again and you are trying to run it a second time which fails. You need to initialize a new `MyThread` object to run it again.

Comment: but how to re-run MyThread? It fires 1 time, but I need to call it constantly. Maybe I chose the wrong way?

Comment: or how to properly initialize it again?